# Does Lua share tables within tables?

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I started developing a game with Love2d engine and Lua, and I have the following code structure.

```
BaseEntity = { 
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        w = 0,
        h = 0,
        img = {},
     }

function BaseEntity:new(obj)
    obj = obj or {}
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end

function BaseEntity:setPos(x, y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end

function BaseEntity:setImage( index, image )
    self.img[index] = image
end

PlayerType  = {["NORMAL"] = 0, ["AI"] = 1}
PlayerState = {["SELECTED"] = 0, ["NOT_SELECTED"] = 1}

Player =    {
                type    = PlayerType.NORMAL,
                state   = PlayerState.NOT_SELECTED
            }

Player = BaseEntity:new(Player)

function Player:new( obj )
    obj = obj or BaseEntity:new()
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end

function Player:setImage( image )
    self.img["sprite"] = image
end
```

When I create a few Player objects and assign different images using `setImage()` function to each object, they all share the same image I assigned to the last object. But when I set different positions to each object using `setPos()` method, they are drawn in correct distinctive positions. Why does it happen like that? Does Lua share the table `img` inside `BaseEntity` with all its instances created from it?

Comment: Do not include `img = {}` inside `BaseEntity`.  Create `img` in constructor `BaseEntity:new(obj)` instead: `obj.img = {}` just before `return obj`

Comment: This line should be hoisted out of the function: `self.__index = self`

Comment: Better rethink your inheritance framework. It's bugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are shared. You have to create separate instance of table if you do not want to share. Note that the x, y ... img you are defining as class variables not as instance variables. To see this, try this code:

```
BaseEntity = { 
        x = 0,
        img = {}, 
     }

function BaseEntity:new(obj)
    obj = obj or {}
    assert(self == BaseEntity)
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    -- obj.img = {}
    self.__index = self
    -- self.__newindex = self
    return obj
end

p1 = BaseEntity:new {y = 1}
p2 = BaseEntity:new {y = 2}

print('p1:', p1.x, p1.y, p1.img)
print('p2:', p2.x, p2.y, p2.img)
print('base:', BaseEntity.x)
p1.x = 3
print('p1:', p1.x, p1.y, p1.img)
print('p2:', p2.x, p2.y, p2.img)
print('base:', BaseEntity.x)
```

This produces this output:

```
p1: 0   1   table: 0x1736430
p2: 0   2   table: 0x1736430
base:   0
p1: 3   1   table: 0x1736430
p2: 0   2   table: 0x1736430
base:   0
```

showing that the table is shared and that when  you write to x, you are writing to the p1 instance not to the class. If now you uncomment the `obj.img` in `new()` the tables of p1 and p2 will no longer be the same: each instance will have its own. If you uncomment the `__newindex` line, you will see that you are then assigning to the BaseEntity "class"

Comment: Thank you for this fine answer. I am new to Lua so still a bit rough around the edges :)